# Build phase script is running before needed files are created in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10, dynamic-frameworks

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/scripts/strip-frameworks.sh

We are always using this script to remove architectures for dynamic frameworks. It has worked with Xcode 9.

In Xcode 10, it didn't remove the architectures.
Anything in Xcode 10 that could break this?
We have a theory that it is related to the new build system

Answer (score 6):

**Solution**

The new build system is now running scripts in parallel if its dependency is already available or if it doesn't have any dependency.
The solution is to provide input files to tell "run scripts" not to run yet without those dependencies.

This is more elaborated in this [post](https://medium.com/xcblog/wwdc18-modern-tips-for-optimising-swift-build-time-in-xcode-10-a81de3a9be6d)

**Alternative Solution:**

We used the legacy build system as a work around.

File > Workspace Settings
[image: File-Workspace-Settings]
[image: New Build System]
[image: Legacy Build System]